# DNS managing, how to do if i have one ip on my vps

Tags: domain-name-system, vps

i'm using vps, which has one ip address, i want to use it for all my domains. But  domain registrants needs two ns servers as minimum. How should i set up things for get all my domains associated with my vps server? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your VPS service ought to offer secondary DNS for you, perhaps free or for a small fee. Or maybe your domain registrar can do it. Have you looked into either of those options?

Answer (score 0):

[afraid.org](http://afraid.org) offers free DNS services. They will also act as a secondary for you :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many companies that offer DNS hosting: [zoneedit](http://zoneedit.com/) has an (initially) free service that may suit your needs, but they'll charge if you have >5 domains, or if any of your domains have high traffic. [dyndns.com](http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/custom/) also offer a commercial zone hosting service.

(I've not used either of these, but I've heard good things about zoneedit from friends)

Answer (score 0):

For the company domain names I'm hosting DNS internally and on my home network (for now) but am also using [everydns](http://www.everydns.com/) as a secondarie. It's a free service. When I registered my personal domain I only had a single DNS server available so used that IP address for both server entries (but with different names) and created the glue records accordingly. That allowed me to satisfy the two server requirement with a single server. Once I had had another DNS server to use I simply updated the records.